# Is it possible to use a Spring Object in a set and as an attribute at the same time?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I think it's easier to explain it than to ask a question. I can not find the formula to do the following:

Imagine that we have a PHOTO Object. On the one hand, we have a NEWS Object that has a PHOTO Object with an @OneToOne relation. On the other hand, we have a PROFILE Object that has an avatar attribute that is a PHOTO Object, also with an @OneToOne relation. At the same time, I want the PROFILE to have an ALBUM Object, which is a set of PHOTO Objects with an @OneToMany relationship.

Hibernate does not let me share @OneToOne and @OneToMany relationships on the same PHOTO Object. I think it can not use the same table to save a PHOTO Object in a @OneToOne and a @OneToMany relation at the same time.

Can someone explain to me why or an alternative way to solve the problem ....

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer, but Hibernate will sometimes be forgiving if you have updatable=false and insertable=false. That way you can have a primary relationship, but other ways to get to the same object.

Comment: I would question the validity of `@OneToOne`. In real-life scenarios, one-to-one relationships are really rare, especially between totally unrelated objects like photos, profiles and news articles. In your case, I believe the same photo can be assigned to a news article as well as a profile, so it cannot have one-to-one relationship with either. The litmus test for a one-to-one relationship is whether two objects must always share the same primary key that is not shared with anything else; then and only then are they one-to-one. In most cases the correct relationship is actually `@ManyToOne`.

Comment: What is a "Spring Object" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `Photo` entity in different entities then keep the `Photo` entity independent and store any relationship in the entity that uses the `Photo` entity or in a mapping table. In your case you can use the following structure.

```
class Profile {

    @oneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="avatar")
    Photo avatar;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="profile_album",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="profile_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="photo_id"))
    Set<Photo> album;
}
```

Your table structure will be like this.

```
photo - id, ...
profile - id, avatar (references photo id), ...
profile_album - profile_id, photo_id // mapping table
```

Comment: Thanks wolverine. That is the correct annotation. Do you know where can I learn more about this type of annotations (inverseJoinColumns)?

Comment: @JorgeM.Nures Read the [user guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)